# Freeform and Abide

Tags: solspace-freeform, validation

What'd be the best practice to add Abide validation to Freeform?

http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/abide.html

```
<form data-abide novalidate>
```

How do I drop something like 'data-abide novalidate' into an EE Freeform tag?

```
{exp:freeform:form
    collection="Contact"
    required="name|email"
    return="contact/thank-you"
    form:id="contact"
    }
```

Comment: You could try using the form:attribute_name parameter https://solspace.com/legacy_docs/freeform-4/form/#form_attribute_name

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
{exp:freeform:form
    collection="Contact"
    required="name||email|message"
    return="contact/thank-you"
    form:id="contact"
    form:data-abide="true"
    form:novalidate="true"
    }
```

This is the documentation on Abide:

```
<form action="" data-abide novalidate method="post">
```

This is how Freeform generates the HTML:

```
<form action="" data-abide="true" novalidate="true" method="post">
```

The confusion comes from the syntax for the attributes. Both of these above are interpreted the same way.